# Indexing in list which contains another set of lists in python

Tags: python-3.x, indexing

How will i access the list in a list?
For example

```
 data = [ [[list([1,2,3]), list([0,1])]], [[list([4,5,6]), list([1,1])]] ]
```

The output data should be

```
output = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: By learning list operations, and in no other way.

Comment: `[d[0][0] for d in data]` as before, with a list comprehension.

Comment: I already found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did

```
>>> data = [ [[list([1,2,3]), list([0,1])]], [[list([4,5,6]), list([1,1])]] ]
>>> output = list([row[0][0] for row in data])
>>> print (output)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Access individual lists as follows by index.

```
data[0] = [[[1, 2, 3], [0, 1]]]
data[0][0] = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1]]
data[0][0][0] = [1, 2, 3]
data[1][0][0] = [4, 5, 6]
```